# How to make sparkling powder for candy?

Tags: candy

When I was young, someone taught me how to make this powder you find on candy.  It's acidic and seems to "sparkle" in the mouth, but I don't know the name and so I can't find a recipe.

I suppose I need to use sodium bicarbonate (baking soda), but aside from that, I can't remember what's in it.

What's the name of this powder and how is it made?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you mean sherbet, which is made by mixing 1 cup of powdered sugar (also called icing or confectioner's sugar) with 1 tsp of baking soda (also called bicarbonate of soda) and 1 tsp of powdered citric acid. Altering the proportion of soda (alkali) to citric acid makes it more or less fizzy.

Comment: Just to add a small note: this is the [UK sense of *sherbet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherbet_(powder)); in the US, *sherbet* more commonly means a frozen dessert similar to sorbet.